# Disable SSH at public, leave on at home

Tags: network, ssh, remote-desktop, sharing, smb

I have SSH (remote login), VNC (screen sharing), and SMB (file sharing) all enabled via the sharing menu in settings. I need these at home. When I go to somewhere & connect to public wifi, these services stay on. Any hacker could try & brute-force my password for these services. They also unnecessarily consume battery away from home charger. **I would like these 3 services (SSH, VNC, SMB) to disable themselves when my mac isnt on the home WIFI.** I am not averse to the terminal and unix-friendly solutions, and I am fine with replacing the inbuilt ssh/vnc/smb servers with 3rd-party servers if there is minimal overhead.

Please dont answer any of the following, I already have considered these:

- Just dont use public wifi
- Disable some of these services
- Make your password longer

Comment: You could enforce public key authentication for SSH at least. But wouldn't using a password of decent length give enough protection against brute-force attacks?

Comment: @nohillside it seems i forgot to add the battery life aspect to my question. I also know that a password of decent length should be ok, but im still curious to somewhat improve security, especially since the same ssh login password can be used to get root.